# `strftime` acting unexpectedly

Tags: python, date

I have the following Python code:

```
from datetime import datetime

def get_session_id(date_of_mri):
    dt = datetime.strptime(date_of_mri, '%m/%d/%Y')
    date_time = dt.strftime("%Y%M%D")
    return date_time

print(get_session_id('2/27/2002'))
```

This prints

```
20020002/27/02
```

I'm expecting it to print

```
20020227
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You want `%Y%m%d` not `%Y%M%D`. You used the right sigils on the parse side; why change to something else on the print side?

Comment: (`%D` is a full date, not the day which is `%d`; and `%M` is minutes, vs `%m` being months)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy. It's interesting. I didn't know for `%D`. I can't find it in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes)

Comment: It's there in the original C strftime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python is case-sensitive, you have to use the same directive as input (%m and %d instead of %M and %D):

```
from datetime import datetime

def get_session_id(date_of_mri):
    dt = datetime.strptime(date_of_mri, '%m/%d/%Y')
    date_time = dt.strftime("%Y%m%d")  # <- here
    return date_time

print(get_session_id('2/27/2002'))
```

Output:

```
20020227
```

Documentation: [strftime() and strptime() Format Codes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes)